# marcar todos los Checkbox de un DataTable con style bootstrap-Switch con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

deseo agregar un input tipo checkbox que me permita marcar como "chequeados" todos los los checkbox que se encuentran en un dataTable, estos checkbox tienen un estilo de **bootstrap-switch** a como pongo se muestra en la siguiente imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
al hacer click en **Seleccionar todos** todos se cambien su **estado a checked**

he probado esto pero no me funciona

```
$('#table_Permisos input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        // toggle checkbox
        $(this).prop('checked',!$(this).prop('checked'));
        // toggle class
        $(this).parents('label').toggleClass('active');
    });c
```

});
cualquier opinion me sera de mucha ayuda de ante mano gracias
parte del codigo html

agrego captura de como agrego los inputs al data table
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? a) No marca los _checkboxes_ b) No aplica estilo a los _switches_ c) Ambas

Comment: no marca los checkboxes de la tabla, permitame la edito

Comment: Agrega `console.log($(this)[0]);` deberías ver en consola cada checkbox, si no, el selector es incorrecto. En todo caso, edita la pregunta para agregar el HTML de la tabla como se ve en el navegador -> ver código fuente, solo un par de filas será suficiente.

Comment: los checkbox los logro ver en consola, pero al querer hacer un prop(checked), no lo hace,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://gitbrent.github.io/bootstrap4-toggle/) solo necesitas ejecutar el método `.bootstrapToggle()` para asignar el nuevo estado `on => activo o checked` u `off => inactivo o !checked` y no se requiere que esté dentro de una etiqueta:

```js
// Marcar o desmarcar todos los checkboxes
$("#todos").on('click', function() {
    // Obtener valor que se aplicará todos en la tabla
    let checked = ($(this).prop('checked')) ? 'on' : 'off';
    $('#table_Permisos input[type="checkbox"]').bootstrapToggle(checked);
});

// Solo para verificar que se actualizan los valores
$('#table_Permisos input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

```css
label.active {
  background:#00a;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_Permisos">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="todos"> Marcar / desmarcar todos</label>
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, aun sigue sin marcar todos los checkbox de la table agregare a la pregunta una captura del columDef de como agrego los checkbox, estoy suponiendo que el plugin de bootstrapSwitch no le deja cambiar el estado, trate de agregar los labels a cada input type check pero sigue sin cambiar el off del cechbox

Comment: @juanchoperez, listo, actualicé la respuesta, ya debe funcionar sin problema.

Comment: muchisimas gracias estimado, me resulto de mucha ayuda tu comentario